# Cursor inside procedure body

Tags: sql, plsql, cursor, oracle12c

I am trying to declare a cursor inside procedure body. 
I know it is supposed to be done in the declare block but the table the cursor refers is created inside the procedure body.

```
--TABLE MAY OR MAY NOT BE PRESENT PRIOR TO PROCEDURE EXECUTION
SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO ln_cnt
  FROM User_Tables
  WHERE table_name = 'TMP$UOM_COMBO_GEN';
  IF ln_cnt > 0 THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' CREATE TABLE TMP$UOM_COMBO_GEN (UOM_ID VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), HIER_CODE VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),NODE_CODE VARCHAR2(200 BYTE))';
  END IF;

  CURSOR C_HIER
  IS
    SELECT DISTINCT HIER_CODE FROM TMP$UOM_COMBO_GEN WHERE UOM_ID=P_UOM_ID;

 FOR HIER IN C_HIER
  LOOP
    IF C_HIER%ROWCOUNT = 1 THEN
      LV_SQL2         := '(SELECT UOM_ID, NODE_CODE '||HIER.HIER_CODE||' FROM TMP$UOM_COMBO_GEN WHERE UOM_ID='''||P_UOM_ID||''' AND HIER_CODE='''||HIER.HIER_CODE||''')'||HIER.HIER_CODE;
      LV_SORT         := ' ORDER BY '||HIER.HIER_CODE||'';
      LV_SQL          := 'SELECT * FROM ' || LV_SQL2;
    ELSE
      LV_SQL3 := ' LEFT OUTER JOIN(SELECT NODE_CODE '||HIER.HIER_CODE||' FROM TMP$UOM_COMBO_GEN WHERE UOM_ID='''||P_UOM_ID||''' AND HIER_CODE='''||HIER.HIER_CODE||''')'||HIER.HIER_CODE ||' ON 1=1';
      LV_SORT := LV_SORT||','||HIER.HIER_CODE||'';
      LV_SQL  := LV_SQL || LV_SQL3;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
```

I am getting the following error.

> Error(17,10): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "C_HIER" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ;

Comment: If you dynamically create a table, you always have to use dynamic SQL to reference it.  You can't open a cursor using static SQL.  Why are you using dynamic SQL to create the table in the first place?  Creating objects at runtime is generally a very poor approach so my initial bias would be to get rid of that approach.  If `TMP$` indicates a temporary table and you actually need a table object rather than, say, a collection, create a global temporary table once and use it like any other table.

Answer (score 0):

Well a table once created is stored in database and u can refer it from wherever u want to refer in the schema .

Also there a change may be required in your code in the following part

```
        SELECT COUNT(*)
          INTO ln_cnt
          FROM User_Tables
          WHERE table_name = 'TMP$UOM_COMBO_GEN';
          IF ln_cnt > 0 THEN -- means only if table exists u want to create the table which will 
         --throw an exception if table is already there , 
         --so better equate it to 0
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' CREATE TABLE TMP$UOM_COMBO_GEN (UOM_ID VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), HIER_CODE VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),NODE_CODE VARCHAR2(200 BYTE))';
          END IF;
```

Now , if u really have a requirement to create a new table every time some condition is true/false and u then want to select the table in a cursor do something like following by using reference cursors

```
        create or replace procedure abc(Table_name varchar2 , param_list varchar2 , where_clause varchar2) is
        c_hier sys_refcursor ;
        LV_SQL2 varchar2(2000) ;
        LV_SORT varchar2(2000) ;
        LV_SQL varchar2(2000) ;
        LV_SQL3 varchar2(2000) ;
        begin
        SELECT COUNT(*)
          INTO ln_cnt
          FROM User_Tables
          WHERE table_name = Table_name; -- Use any table here 
          IF ln_cnt = 0 THEN
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' CREATE TABLE '||Table_name||' '||param_list;
            END IF;

          open c_hier for 'SELECT DISTINCT '||param_list||' FROM '||table_name||' '||where_clause; 

         FOR HIER IN C_HIER
          LOOP
            IF C_HIER%ROWCOUNT = 1 THEN
              LV_SQL2         := '(SELECT UOM_ID, NODE_CODE '||HIER.HIER_CODE||' FROM TMP$UOM_COMBO_GEN WHERE UOM_ID='''||P_UOM_ID||''' AND HIER_CODE='''||HIER.HIER_CODE||''')'||HIER.HIER_CODE;
              LV_SORT         := ' ORDER BY '||HIER.HIER_CODE||'';
              LV_SQL          := 'SELECT * FROM ' || LV_SQL2;
            ELSE
              LV_SQL3 := ' LEFT OUTER JOIN(SELECT NODE_CODE '||HIER.HIER_CODE||' FROM TMP$UOM_COMBO_GEN WHERE UOM_ID='''||P_UOM_ID||''' AND HIER_CODE='''||HIER.HIER_CODE||''')'||HIER.HIER_CODE ||' ON 1=1';
              LV_SORT := LV_SORT||','||HIER.HIER_CODE||'';
              LV_SQL  := LV_SQL || LV_SQL3;
            END IF;
          END LOOP;
```